# How to get referential data in Soft Delete?

Tags: c#, .net-core

While getting parent Data i also get Child data which is shown in my code, To get rid of this i have used foreach loop but when the db is too large it is not good approach. Please help

```
 public async Task<DataSourceResult> GetAll(DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var data = _unitOfWork.SchoolsRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
                                                .Include(x => x.SchoolBranches)
                                                .ThenInclude(y => y.Classes)                                                
                                                .ToDataSourceResult(request);
            List<Schools> result = (List<Schools>)data.Data;
            if (result != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    var schoolBranch = item.SchoolBranches.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).ToList();
                    foreach (var _item in schoolBranch)
                    {
                        var _class = _item.Classes.Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted).ToList();
                        _item.Classes = _class;
                    }
                    item.SchoolBranches = schoolBranch;
                }
                data.Data = result;
                return data;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FriendlyExceptionHandler("No data found!", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
```

I expect School Data(parent) with their child who are not SoftDeleted in the db.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow! You can format the programm code in your question better with the grave accent character `code` or tripple ```, for multi-line code blocks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter?

```
var data = _unitOfWork.SchoolsRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
                                                    .IncludeFilter(x => x.SchoolBranches.Where(i => !i.IsDeleted))
                                                    .ThenInclude(y => y.Classes)                                                
                                                    .ToDataSourceResult(request);
```

Comment: After IncludeFilter "ThenInclude" is not Showing